# Migration path for Sony PRS-650 notes

Tags: annotations, sony-prs-650

I've a Sony PRS-650 with lots of notes (highlighted text in books). Is there any tool which can migrate these notes to other ebook readers' format or is there any other e-book reader which supports Sony's notes? (Is newer Sony Readers use the same format at all?)

What kind of device could I buy without losing my notes?

Answer (score 3):

The Sony Reader software that came with the reader has an option to export notes as an RTF file. I'm not sure whether or not you can import the notes into another device though.

I'm not able to find a user manual and I don't have the software on this laptop (I do on my other one, so perhaps I can find the information later). However, I did find a [blog](http://blog.the-ebook-reader.com/2010/10/18/sony-prs-650-and-350-shortcuts-tips-and-tricks/) that gives a basic step-by-step of how to export the notes:

> **Export Notes and Highlights:**
>
> Plug the Reader into your computer with
>   the USB cable, open the Reader software if it doesn’t open
>   automatically, navigate to the book with the notes/highlights using
>   Sony’s Reader software, open it, and then click the green icon on the
>   lower left to export the notes as an RTF file.